# mingw32 w64 missing OpenGL32 lib

Tags: c++, opengl, static-libraries

I use Mingw32 w64 on Win64 (x86_64-w64-mingw32). I have not found libopengl32.a in the GCC 4.7.1 ruben build.

How I can obtain the lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways to solve your problem:

1. Go to http://www.equation.com. There is another 64-bit MinGW build and it contains libopengl32.a which I successfully have used.
2. Use some GL loading library, like [GLee](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/) or [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net). They just load the opengl32.dll dll directly and avoid using export lib file.